# PHP passing parameters while creating new object, call_user_func_array for objects

Tags: php

I would like to dynamically create a PHP object, and parameters would be optional.

For example, instead of doing this:

```
$test = new Obj($param);
```

I would like to do something like this (create new ob is fictional):

```
$test = create_new_obj('Obj', $param);
```

Is there such function in php? Something similar to call_user_func_array, but for object instead.

Comment: to clarify a bit more, the class name is variable (it changes), and $param depends on the class that is loaded. Sometimes there's no param. It is basically dynamically loading from a variety of classes depending on the situation.

Comment: I think my answer below still fits the bill from what you're describing (variable class names, optional construction parameters).  There's no reason you can't pass a null `$param` to a constructor for a class that doesn't need it.  If, on the other hand, you are saying that the type of object that gets created is actually *dependant on `$param`*, then you'll want to look into something like the Factory Pattern:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern.  PHP can't handle your construction decisions for you in that case... you'll need to write logic to decide what gets built.

Answer (score 28):

As of PHP 5.6, you can now achieve this with a single line of code by using the new Argument Unpacking operator (...).

Here is a simple example.

```
$className='Foo';
$args=['arg1','arg2','arg3'];

$newClassInstance=new $className(...$args);
```

See [PHP Variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) for more information.

Comment: shouldn't need more than 1 line in 5.5- either then. `$db = (new ReflectionClass ( 'Foo' ))->newInstanceArgs ( $args );`

Answer (score 18):

Since some constructors may take a variable number of arguments, the following method should be used to accommodate it.

```
$r = new ReflectionClass($strClassName);
$myInstance = $r->newInstanceArgs($arrayOfConstructorArgs);
```

For example, if your `Car` constructor took 3 args

```
$carObj = new Car($color, $engine, $wheels);
```

Then

```
$strClassName = 'Car';
$arrayOfConstructorArgs = array($color, $engine, $wheels);
$r = new ReflectionClass($strClassName);
$carObj = $r->newInstanceArgs($arrayOfConstructorArgs);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php

Comment: Reflection is expensive.  You'd be better off using `func_get_args()` for this.

Comment: In my tests using reflection in php isn't slower than func\_get\_args(). Plus you don't have to change the code of the classes.

Answer (score 7):

In such cases i use factory-methods. they can be easily defined in abstract classes:

```
class Foobar {

    public function __construct($foo, $bar) 
    {
        // do something
    }

    static public function factory($foo, $bar) 
    {
        return new self($foo, $bar);
    }
}
```

with this you can use `call_user_func_array()`:

```
$my_foobar_obj = call_user_func_array('Foobar::factory', array($foo, $bar));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can dynamically create an object as long as you know the class name:

```
$objName = 'myClass';
$test = new $objName($param);
```

You could easily define a `__construct()` function to take [default arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) as well if that was a requirement of your construction logic.

[Edit note]: This is a concept known as [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), and there's some examples in the manual where the [new](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) command is introduced.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a clean version of what you wanted:

```
class ClassName {
    public static function init(){       
        return (new ReflectionClass(get_called_class()))->newInstanceArgs(func_get_args());        
    }

    public static function initArray($array=[]){       
        return (new ReflectionClass(get_called_class()))->newInstanceArgs($array);        
    }

    public function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){
        ///construction code
    } 
}
```

**Normal ugly method of creating a new object instance using new**

```
$obj = new ClassName('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
echo $obj->method1()->method2();
```

**Static call using init instead of new**

```
echo ClassName::init('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')->method1()->method2();
```

**Static call using initArray instead of new**

```
echo ClassName::initArray(['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])->method1()->method2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @chris' answer( https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550465/1806628 ), here is a usage of reflection classes:

```
abstract class A{
    // the constructor writes out the given parameters
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump(func_get_args());
    }

    public function copy(){
        // find our current class' name, __CLASS__ would return A
        $thisClass = get_class($this);
        $tmp = new ReflectionClass($thisClass);
        // pass all the parameters recieved to the new object
        $copy = $tmp->newInstanceArgs(func_get_args());

        return $copy;
    }
}

class B extends A{}

// create a new B object, with no parameters
$b = new B();

// create another b, but with other parameters
$c = $b->copy('the parameter of the copied B');
```

This is useful, if you want to make an object copy function in an ancestor class and don't know, whether child classes need parameters in the future, or not.